# Jquery animation callback issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to build a simple carousel animation with jQuery. There are 3 viewable images at any one time with buttons to click on each side to go forward or backwards. The center image is raised up by 30px to be given prominence. When one of the buttons is pushed the center image should drop down then all three images move together left or right.

The initial up and down animation works but on a callback none of the other animations will work. If I hard code the direction into them only one of them works. Is there something wrong with my current code or approach?

```
ctr_right.click(function() { carouselAnimate("right") });
ctr_left.click(function() { carouselAnimate("left") });

function carouselAnimate(direction) {
    var offset = img_width + img_offset;
    img_focus.animate({"top": "+="+focus_offset}, "slow", function() {
        img_left.animate({direction: "-="+offset}, "slow"); 
        img_focus.animate({direction: "-="+offset}, "slow");    
        img_right.animate({direction: "-="+offset}, "slow");    
    });

};
```

Comment: is this your full code? where is direction used?

Comment: agree, need more code.  And putting "+=" and "-=" in the CSS object like that I'm pretty sure just won't work.

Comment: There is more code but this is the relevant stuff. From my explanation at the top the variables kind of explain themselves.

@mVChr  
From http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options
"Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with a leading += or -= sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think direction should always be "left", and based on what I assume direction is, you'll want to add or remove the offset. Switching between setting a left/right position isn't a good approach, I don't think.

What's less clear to me is why you're animating several things the same way separately. Wouldn't this work just as well:

```
ctr_right.click(function() { carouselAnimate("right") });
ctr_left.click(function() { carouselAnimate("left") });

function carouselAnimate(direction) {
    var offset = img_width + img_offset;
    img_focus.animate({"top": "+="+focus_offset}, "slow", function() {
        $(img_left, img_focus, img_right).each(function(){
           $(this).animate({direction: "-="+offset}, "slow");
        }); 
    });

};
```

A final thought; If the above doesn't answer your question, look into queue:false within jquery's animate options.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options

Comment: Thanks for this matrym this is what I needed. The left value was being properly computed but since i was using a mix of left and right it was getting all confused. Everything is now calculated from the left to make it easier.
I also like your example of using the .each function. This is much cleaner but the way you have it setup it does not work. Only the first item in the selection gets called. If I change the each to:  $.each([img_left, img_focus, img_right], function()....
Then it works fine. I'm not really sure why.

Comment: @Chris The each you're using in your comment processes an array rather than a set of jQuery selected dom objects. if you had previously stated $imgs = $("#img_left, #img_focus, #img_right"), then I think you should be able to do $imgs.each(function...